# ruby use array tvalues to index nested hash of hash

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I want to do something like this,

I have a hash of hash built like this.

```
h = {1 => {2 => {3 => "three"}},'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => "basd"}}}
=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"basd"}}, 1=>{2=>{3=>"three"}}}
```

If I have an array with values like this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to have a method which will use the array values to index nested keys in my hash and return the value pointed by last key (as guided by previous array/keys)
for eg.

```
getHashValue([1,2,3]) should return "three" => h[1][2][3]
```

`if a = ['a','b', 'c']` then the return value should be `basd`.

How to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And then there's:

```
keys.inject(hash, :fetch)
```

or for earlier Ruby versions:

```
keys.inject(hash) {|h, k| h[k]}
```

If you did want to use recursion, a more Rubyesque approach would be:

```
def get_value(obj, keys)
  keys.empty? ? obj : get_value(obj[keys[0]], keys[1..-1])
end
```

Comment: Anything wrong in my try?                                    irb(main):2552:0> h
=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"basd"}}, 1=>{2=>{3=>"three"}}}
irb(main):2553:0> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):2554:0> a.inject(h, :[])
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
        from (irb):2554:in `inject'
        from (irb):2554
irb(main):2555:0> a.inject(h, :fetch)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
        from (irb):2555:in `inject'
        from (irb):2555

Comment: @user2562153 I started with Ruby from 1.9.3. So if that's the case go with *megar* solution.

Comment: In earlier versions of Ruby, such as yours, inject required a block, so the form you'd have to use is `keys.inject(hash) {|h, k| h[k]}`

Comment: Hi Peter, inject now works with a block. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a new method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array` that solves this problem entirely.

It returns `nil` if an element is missing at any level of nesting.

```
h1 = {}
h2 = { a: {} }
h3 = { a: { b: {} } }
h4 = { a: { b: { c: 100 } } }

h1.dig(:a, :b, :c) # => nil
h2.dig(:a, :b, :c) # => nil
h3.dig(:a, :b, :c) # => nil
h4.dig(:a, :b, :c) # => 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple recursion

```
def getValue(hash, keys, i = 0)
  if i + 1 < keys.length
    getValue(hash[keys[i]], keys, i + 1)
  else
    hash[keys[i]]
  end
end

getValue(h, [1,2,3]) => "three"
getValue(h, ['a','b','c']) => "basd"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {1 => {2 => {3 => "three"}},'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => "basd"}}}
a = ['a','b', 'c']
a.inject(h, :[]) # => "basd"

h = {1 => {2 => {3 => "three"}},'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => "basd"}}}
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.inject(h, :[]) # => "three"
```

Comment: Hi Priti, I get "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)" from the inject operation, above. Anything wrong in my try or understanding?

Comment: @user2562153 On what `ruby` version you are now?

Comment: ruby 1.8.6 (2009-08-04 patchlevel 383) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Hi Priti, How do I achieve the same with Ruby Version 1.8.6?

Comment: See comment on my answer.